# Converting string to bytes prints weird-looking hex-code in console

Tags: python, c++, networking, udp

**Introduction my problem:**

I am trying to write a C++ program that receives data over UDP using WinSock2.
For that, I have a prewritten Python script that sends 10-byte packets to a specified port, where the C++ program then receives them. I have gotten the data transfer to work, however I am confused about the data that is being sent.

**My problem:**
I am running the Python script from cmd, which prints the sent text on console. I have also added a line into the script, which converts the string to bytes to verify, what exactly is being sent. The first line is the one I added, fairly simple:

```
logger.debug("Sending packet len %s, data %s", sizeof(packet), bytes(packet))
logger.debug("Sending packet len %s, data %s", sizeof(packet), packet)
```

And this is the output in my terminal (from 3 different packets sent):

[image: Image here]

What confuses me, is I would expect the hex code to contain only hexadecimal symbols, but instead there are some quite seemingly random symbols/letters there as well, even though the actual printed text looks just fine. Can someone explain to me, where do these symbols come from, as I am not sure how am I supposed to interpret this information on the receiving end in my C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script does not print plain hex, but the interpreted hex string. Some of your hex chars are interpretable and displayable in ASCII, others are not. I tested the string replacement in my interpreter and you see the same results:

```
>>> "%s".encode() % b"\xfa\x3f\x00"
b'\xfa?\x00'
```

With `\x3f` being the ASCII hex code for `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Python tries to be helpful (whether it actually helps is debatable) by printing bytes which correspond to an ASCII symbol as the ASCII symbol.

```
>>> t1 = b'test'
>>> t2 = b'\x74\x65\x73\x74'
>>> t1 == t2
True
>>> print(t1, t2)
b'test' b'test'
```